# Utility to tag regions of audio files

Tags: audio, utilities

For example, say I have a recording with lots of noise and people speaking, I'd like to tag areas where people are speaking with a 1, and by default everywhere else is 0. Then save this file separately, one tag per sample.

*mhWaveEdit* has an ideal user interface to do this, but this tagging functionality isn't included and the project seems to be moribund at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to add new functionality to *mhWaveEdit*. Get the source and look at some of the existing functions in `mainwindow.c`. You'll be using `w->doc->chunk->length`, `w->doc->selstart`, and `w->doc->selend`. There is a function `create_menu` where you can insert some menu items in `menu_items1[]`, and because the functionality is probably based on selection, you'll need to revise `need_selection_names[]`. The selection size is 1:1 with actual samples, you don't have to worry about scaling or translation in the UI.

Good luck!